# how public is a github public repo?

Tags: version-control, open-source, github

I am finally moving to GitHub for source control. We can only use a public repo for a project were doing, but how **public** is public? Is it safe to assume that if I do not publicize the project at all, no one will really find it among the 3 mil repos they already have?

I cannot really have people seeing the source code as of right now, but 7/mo is a little steep for needing just 1 private repo.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. That's not a safe assumption. GitHub has a search engine for public repos, and people use it (including myself). So, there's always a decent possibility that someone will see your source-code. If you want a free private repo, I suggest using [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) instead, or another service that offers free private repos. Note that BitBucket is only free if you have 5 or fewer users working in your repo.

Comment: Gitorious also offers private hosting for free I believe.

Answer (score 9):

When asking yourself such questions, you should consider that a lot of website visitors are *other computers*, not humans. The google bot is indexing every page it can find, ohloh.net creates statistics over open source projects on github, ... and so on and so forth. So if something is on the Internet, people will find it. :)